# Organizing a set of sets by size in Java

Tags: java, set, subset, treeset, overriding

I'm writing a simple program to recursively find all subsets of some larger set. I've got it working, but I wanted to order all of the sets in order by size.

I posted my working code below.

```
import java.util.*;
public class AllSubsets {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      // Change contents of this array to easily change contents of set.
      Integer[] setContents = {3, 6, 8, 9, 10, 22};
      // create initial unused set by dumping all of the aray into a set.
      Set<Integer> unused = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(setContents));
      // create initial empty set for used set.
      Set<Integer> used = new HashSet<Integer>();
      // create output set of sets.
      Set<Set<Integer>> allSets = new HashSet<Set<Integer>>();
      allSets.add(used);
      // find all sets recursively
      findAllSets(used, unused, allSets);
      // print out results
      System.out.println(allSets);
   }

   public static void findAllSets(Set<Integer> used, Set<Integer> unused,
                                  Set<Set<Integer>> allSets) {
      if (unused != null) {
         Set<Integer> copyOfUnused = new HashSet<Integer>(unused);
         for (Integer val : copyOfUnused) {
            unused.remove(val);
            used.add(val);
            allSets.add(new HashSet<Integer>(used));
            findAllSets(used, unused, allSets);
            used.remove(val);
            unused.add(val);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I was wondering what the best way would be to order these sets by size. I tried to create a TreeSet which holds multiple HashSet objects with it's comparator method overwritten. This ended up compiling but didn't store the values correctly. The code for this I wrote is very similar to the code above, so I will write out the main difference below:

```
  Set<Set<Integer>> allSets =
     new TreeSet<Set<Integer>>(new Comparator<Set<Integer>>() {
        public int compare(Set<Integer> a, Set<Integer> b) {
           return a.size() - b.size();
        }
     });
```

In this version of the code, it compiles but the objects are not storing correctly. The proper sets are being computed and added to "allSets" in the recursive method (tested using println) but it only ever holds one set at a time. I have a feeling it's mostly because I overwrote the Comparator for Set but I am using HashSets. Is there a better way to organize my sets or maybe just a small bug in my code?

Thanks!!

Comment: Rather than create a Set of Sets as your output create a List of Sets and write a comparator.

Comment: I don't know if you are using Java 8, but if you are you can do `Comparator.comparingInt(Set::size)`.

Comment: @bhspencer Does that mean I need to manually check is the element exists inside the list before adding it? A list doesn't preserve the property that all elements must be unique right? Sets do that automatically for me so that is why I used a set.

Comment: @PaulBoddington I am using Java 8 but I have never seen that syntax before. Can you explain it to me in more detail? Thanks!

Comment: Not easily as I'm using my mobile, making typing v tricky. Google "method references" and look at the documentation for the Comparator class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TreeSet<Set<Integer>>` will only store one Set element with a given size, because it considers two different sets with the same size to be "equal": it takes `a.compareTo(b) == 0` to mean `a == b`.

If you want to get all of the sets and then print them in order of size, gather all of the sets in a regular (Hash)Set, and then sort the entries:

```
List<Set<Integer>> listOfSets = new ArrayList<>(allSets);
Collections.sort(listOfSets, <your comparator above>);
System.out.println(listOfSets).
```

Comment: Wow thanks for the quick response and really good explanation! That makes complete sense, I forgot that Sets also have to use the Comparator to add and see if the elements are equivalent. I got it working!!